# How to set up Google Apps Gmail on an Android -phone?

Tags: email, gmail, imap, google-apps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Firm Gmail, i.e. Google Apps -email, with K9 -email program?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/29193/firm-gmail-i-e-google-apps-email-with-k9-email-program)

I have this kind of firm url, `https://www.google.com/a/cpanel/firm.com`. I want to have an IMAP -email account on Android. How can I do it?

I am using the app `"My email"` by which things do not work. If I use the native Gmail -app, things work out of the box. As for the `"My email"` -software (that gathers all emails, not just Gmails, under one mailbox), I selected

```
imap
Email: myName@firm.com
```

**Incoming**

```
Username: myName
Imap Server: imap.gmail.com
Port: 993
Security SSL
```

**Outgoing**

```
SMTP server: smtp.gmail.com
Port: 465
Security: SSL
Require sign-in: yes
Use the same settings as the incoming server: yes
```

Pressing `Next` fires `"Username or password incorrect"` with `"s@gmail@firmA@g"` while `"Unable to open connection to server"` with the latter. So how can set up the Google Apps Gmail on Android?

Comment: If it's Google Apps Gmail you shouldn't need to do anything special with the Gmail app. Add the account MyName@firm.com and give it your password. My company has a Google Apps setup and it works just fine for me.

Comment: Do you by any chance use two factor authentication?

Comment: **[UPDATE] This solution should work [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/29197/16903), haven't tested but I am pretty sure. I flagged for Closing due to duplicate.**

Answer (score 2):

For the incoming username, you need to use your complete email address ("myName@firm.com"), not just the account username ("myName").

Comment: Not working, the same err.

Comment: Then one of the following should be true: you're entering some of the information incorrectly, the app you're using is broken, or Google has locked your account for too many failed login attempts.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable IMAP on your account.

See Google Help Page here: http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=77695

Comment: ...this is enabled and I still get the errs.