# Firm Gmail, i.e. Google Apps -email, with K9 -email program?

Tags: gmail, imap, google-apps, k9-mail

> *I am struggling with this kind of Google Apps -site, example from Google.com -site [here](https://www.google.com/a/google.com).*
>
> [image]

I use two email-clients in Android: default Gmail -client (because it is tied to my Gmail) and K9. I am able to set up all Gmails to K9 but one email i.e. the firm email from the site `https://www.google.com/a/firm.com` (excluding ofc the Android-tied-gmail -account, more [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/29194/all-emails-under-k9-app)). It means that I am using K9 and default Gmail-Android -program but I would like to have all emails under K9. Is it possible and how can do it here in the case of the Gmails targeted to firms? I think such gmails are called something like Google App or something like that, not sure.

The firm Gmail is not accepted like this in K9:

> Username: forname.surname
>
> Password: correct
>
> IMAP server: mail.myFirm.com
>
> Security type: SSL (always)
>
> Port: 993
>
> Use compression on network: Mobile Wi-Fi Other

If I change the IMAP -server to `mail.gmail.com`, it gets accepted but it won't work correctly -- redirection problem. But now I am stucked why it does not accept the above settings?!

**Perhaps useful to other like-minded**

> 1. [All emails under K9 -app?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/29194/all-emails-under-k9-app)
> 2. [Email-client with Sent emails from many emails under IMAP?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/29065/email-client-with-sent-emails-from-many-emails-under-imap)
> 3. Setting up IMAP over device-swarm that has a Debian Desktop -client, more [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/182414/email-client-such-as-evolution-with-sent-emails-folder).

Comment: ...this issue is solved!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default settings by K9 have at least two mistakes:

> 1. use `imap.gmail.com` instead of `mail.gmail.com`.
> 2. use full emails for usernames such as `forname.surname@myFirm.com`, not just `forname.surname`.

**Example settings**

> **Incoming Email settings**
>
> > Username: **forname.surname@myFirm.com**
> >
> > Password: correct
> >
> > IMAP server: **imap.gmail.com**
> >
> > Security type: SSL (always)
> >
> > Port: 993
> >
> > Use compression on network: Mobile Wi-Fi Other
>
> **Outgoing Email settings**
>
> > Outgoing Server Name: **smtp.gmail.com**
> >
> > Use Authentication: Yes
> >
> > Use STARTTLS: Yes (some clients call this SSL)
> >
> > Outgoing Server Port: 465 or 587
> >
> > Username: **forname.surname@myFirm.com**

Some useful information extracted from this blog [here](http://help.slamdot.com/idx/28/177/Email-Setup-Tutorials/Google-Apps-Email-Server-Settings).

Comment: That is not a feasible solution! K-9 Mail is a google project and google needs to fix that K-9 can connect in a *secure* way to gmail servers.