# All emails under K9 -app?

Tags: k9-mail

Android requires at least one-working Gmail that is apparently tied to the default email. Now I would like to have that email under K9 but I cannot because Android instructs me to hard-reset my device if I remove the Gmail from the default Gmail. Now the problem is that I get two notification from Default client and from K9. So how can I have all emails under K9?

Comment: why do you ask twice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to remove default Google Account or factory reset to ditch double notifications. Use any one of following methods which suits you best:

- From `Settings` ~> `Accounts & Sync`, choose the default Google Account & **turn off Gmail Sync**. After that, you'll receive notifications from K-9 Mail, ONLY.
- In some Android versions, if you turn off all sync options listed under a Google Account, a *Sign Out* button is appeared. All you need is to tap it. Go ahead to try it.
- If you are rooted, delete `/data/system/accounts.db` file & restart the system (On Jelly Bean, its `/data/system/users/0/accounts.db` and the location can vary with Android versions). Next time, you'll be asked to add Google Account again.