# How do I setup a Gmail account with 2-step verification in K-9 Mail?

Tags: gmail, google-account, k9-mail, 2-step-verification

I'm trying to setup my Gmail account in K-9 Mail, but when I'm setting up the incoming server, I keep getting the error: "Wrong username or password". When I'm trying to set up an outgoing server, I get an error which directs me to the two-step verification at Google.

I have 2-step verification configured on my Google account, but can't seem to get this into K-9 Mail. I've searched all over and tried following different guides, e.g. [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/29193/firm-gmail-i-e-google-apps-email-with-k9-email-program/29197#29197), and I've also tried to change the password on my Google account but nothing helped.

How can I properly configure K-9 Mail for my Gmail account with 2-step verification?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

IMAP clients generally need to use [application-specific passwords](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833) in order to access accounts that use 2-step verification. You'll need to generate a new app-specific password, then use that to set up your incoming/outgoing servers *instead of* using your regular account password. Google's support page (linked above) includes instructions for doing this. Summarized, the procedure is:

> ## How to generate an application-specific password
>
> 1. Visit your [Google Account settings page](https://www.google.com/settings/account).
> 2. On the left, click **Security**.
> 3. Under the "Signing in to Google" topic, click **App Passwords**.
> 4. Using the dropdown menus within under the **App Passwords** section,  select which application you would like to generate a
>    password for along with the device then click "GENERATE". You'll then
>    see the application-specific password (ASP) you just created along
>    with instructions on how to use it.
> 5. When you sign in to an application requiring an ASP, enter your ASP in the password field, and make sure you check the "Remember password"
>    option if you want the application to remember the code.

Comment: Thanks, it was becoming a mystery.  Unfortunately, it seems that you may only have the application specific password when you are using 2xFactor-authentication.  That prevents two people sharing the same mail folders.  Still looking for how to access that emai login.

Answer (score 2):

I had a hard time to resolve the same problem because my Gmail accound wasn't correctly configured with 2-step verification. In case it might help somebody, here is how to do that :

> ## [Turn on 2-Step Verification](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185839)
>
> 1. Go to the [2-Step Verification](https://myaccount.google.com/security/signinoptions/two-step-verification) page. You might have to sign in to your Google Account.
> 2. Select Get started.
> 3. Follow the step-by-step setup process.
>
>    - You will be sent an SMS with a code, and you have to enter the code you just received by SMS.